# Approaches of sending file from server to browser without asking to click on download link

Tags: python, socket.io

What i am trying to ask is, i have a website which takes the user profile and generates some kind of user specific reports in pdf. Pdf is generated at back end. So when user clicks on "generate" button, it should show blocking message and once the file is generated blocking message is removed and file is displayed with  tag.

I am able to do this with help of socket.io and to be very Frank I copied this solution from one blog without understanding much. So my stack is Python and socket.io is on node. While it worked perfectly on my dev machine but on server its keep on throwing connection error message in JavaScript and post message fails on back end. So I am currently having issues with front and back end. And thanks to my blindly copy paste thing I am kind of clueless about the fix.

Is there any alternative to this approach? I can think of using Python based socket io (this time I will read and implement ) but something similar can be achieved by any other approach? I am using this to only send the  generated pad back to client there is no other communication b/w client and server.

*Adding code*

It works like, client opens the download/generate page and gets the ID assigned, once generate button is clicked ID is sent to back-end, now celery generates the PDF (converts to base64) and then posts that on nodejs/notify with ID. Now the socket.io is already listening on /notify url, so once the data is posted its displayed in browser.

Browser -> sock (register) -> AJAX -> Celery (task) ->  on nodejs/notify -> browser sockio client displays the data

Here is the code,

**Client / Browser code**

```
 // func called on generate btn press
 $client.on('notify', function(result) {
        $.unblockUI();
        // alert('In Receiving function...');
        var $obj = $('#dynamic-pdf');
        $obj.hide();
        $obj.attr('data', result);
        $obj.show();
        $('button#view-again').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#previe').modal('show');
    });

    blockWithMsg("Generating PDF, Please Wait...");

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        data: {clientId: $clientId},
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'},
    }); 
    // func finished

   <!-- register client on page load -->
   <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script>
      var $client = io('http://localhost:3000'),
          $clientId = null;

      $client.on('register', function(id) {
          $clientId = id;
      });

    </script>
```

**Node js code**

```
var app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Accept URL-encoded body in POST request.
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000}));
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));

// Echo the client's ID back to them when they connect.
io.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.emit('register', client.id);
});

// Forward task results to the clients who initiated them.
app.post('/notify', function(request, response) {
    var client = io.sockets.connected[request.body.clientId];
    client.emit('notify', request.body.result);
    response.type('text/plain');
    response.send('Result broadcast to client.');
});

server.listen(3000);
```

I am getting emit on undefined value error

Comment: You should post a snippet of what your actual code looks like. Hard to respond without seeing anything.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The error was I started site on different domain than one mentioned in the socket.io connection (which was still localhost) in browser JavaScript.